# Error: "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db_example.table' doesn't exist" even thought Hibernate says the table was created

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I'm trying to build a little web application using Spring, MySQL, Thymeleaf, and Hibernate. Whenever I try making my API call to collect my form data and add it to my database it give me the error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db_example.bottlecaps' doesn't exist` While I didn't explicitly create that table using a query I am using the `@Entity` and `@Table` syntax from `import javax.persistence` to create the table for me. And even when I start up my app Hibernate does print in the logs that the table is being created:

```
2020-06-19 12:43:33.050  WARN 8576 --- [  restartedMain] org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode  : [THYMELEAF][restartedMain] Template Mode 'LEGACYHTML5' is deprecated. Using Template Mode 'HTML' instead.
2020-06-19 12:43:33.149  INFO 8576 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-06-19 12:43:33.193  INFO 8576 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-19 12:43:33.195  INFO 8576 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
Hibernate: create table bottlecaps (id binary(255) not null, brand varchar(255), image-link varchar(255), country varchar(255), description varchar(255), is_alcoholic bit, name varchar(255), year-found integer, year-made integer, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2020-06-19 12:43:33.526  INFO 8576 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-19 12:43:33.806  INFO 8576 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
```

If we continue a little further down the logs you can see where it tries to add my info to the table when I call the API, but then fails.

```
Hibernate: select bottlecap0_.id as id1_0_0_, bottlecap0_.brand as brand2_0_0_, bottlecap0_.image-link as image3_0_0_, bottlecap0_.country as country4_0_0_, bottlecap0_.description as descript5_0_0_, bottlecap0_.is_alcoholic as is_alcoh6_0_0_, bottlecap0_.name as name7_0_0_, bottlecap0_.year-found as year8_0_0_, bottlecap0_.year-made as year9_0_0_ from bottlecaps bottlecap0_ where bottlecap0_.id=?
2020-06-19 12:44:12.971 ERROR 8576 --- [0.1-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'db_example.bottlecaps' doesn't exist
2020-06-19 12:44:12.980 DEBUG 8576 --- [0.1-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2020-06-19 12:44:12.989 ERROR 8576 --- [0.1-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
```

Here is my application.properties file. In a similar post, I have seen people ask for this

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB

# ===============================
# TOMCAT
# ===============================
server.address=127.0.0.1
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true

# ===============================
# = LOGGING
# ===============================
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR

# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username= user
spring.datasource.password= pass
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true

spring.datasource.platform=mysql


# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy


# ===============================
# = Thymeleaf configurations
# ===============================
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

I will also include where I create my object and table as well as its controller

```
package com.example.form.domain;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "bottlecaps", schema ="db_example")
public class Bottlecap {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name="year-made")
    private Integer yearMade;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name="image-link")
    private String capImageLink; //S3 key

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="year-found")
    private Integer yearFound;

    @Column(name="isAlcoholic")
    private Boolean isAlcoholic;

    public Bottlecap() {

    }

    public Bottlecap(UUID id, String name, String brand, Integer yearMade,
                     String country, String capImageLink, String description,
                     Integer yearFound, Boolean isAlcoholic) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.yearMade = yearMade;
        this.country = country;
        this.capImageLink = capImageLink;
        this.description = description;
        this.yearFound = yearFound;
        this.isAlcoholic = isAlcoholic;
    }
    //Getters and Setters down here
}
```

```
package com.example.form.controllers;

import com.example.form.domain.Bottlecap;
import com.example.form.domain.User;
import com.example.form.repository.BottlecapRepository;
import com.example.form.service.BottlecapService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

@Controller
public class BottlecapController {

    private BottlecapService bottlecapService;

    private BottlecapRepository bottlecapRepository;

    public BottlecapController(BottlecapService bottlecapService, BottlecapRepository bottlecapRepository) {
        this.bottlecapService = bottlecapService;
        this.bottlecapRepository = bottlecapRepository;
    }

    // Return registration form template
    @RequestMapping(value="/bottlecap-entry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showEntryPage(ModelAndView modelAndView, Bottlecap bottlecap){
        modelAndView.addObject("bottlecap", bottlecap);
        modelAndView.setViewName("entry");
        return modelAndView;
    }


    @PostMapping("/bottlecap-entry")
    private void entryForm(@Valid Bottlecap bottlecap, @RequestParam(value = "file")MultipartFile image){


            bottlecap.setId(UUID.randomUUID());


            bottlecapService.saveCap(bottlecap);

            //bottlecapService.uploadEntryImage(bottlecap.getId(), image);




    }
}
```

This is my first project where I am attempting to do something like this so any and all feedback is welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `schema ="db_example"` from the `@Table` annotation and see what happens. It is very rare to specify schema names.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for replying. I tried removing that, but the errors are still printing out identical

Comment: Shouldn't be identical if you changed the code. The table name in the error message should have changed, or you didn't change the code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

@mtibo I think as `@Andreas` say to remove a `schema` from the `@Table` annotation....and as you do but I think you forgot to update your `application.properties` file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=<your-database-dialect>
```

`create-drop` -> Every time you run your code it recreates everything

`update` -> Didn't create tables again

and may I ask you why you took `UUID` as the primary key?

I want to write into comments but my reputation is less than `50`. So, I have to upload it as an answer.